# Name of Ionic's popover-style pages?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic Framework *(3.9.2)* I have a `viewDidLeave` event handler that checks the name of the exiting view (a page) before deciding on some action:

```
this.appCtrl.viewDidLeave.subscribe((view)=>
{
  const pageName = view.data && view.data.component && view.data.component.name   // Modals
                || view.component && view.component.name;                         // Pages
  if (pageName === 'SelectPopover') return;

  // ...
```

But I discovered that (for example) when I click a dropdown (`<select>`) menu, the options are shown in a component that is actually considered a "view" by Ionic!  I.e. it fires `viewDidLeave`, and has the name "SelectPopover".  So now I know to ignore views named "SelectPopover" (hence the early `return` in my code snippet), but what other gotchas exist?

I.e. are there any other page/view names I should also ignore here because they are used internally by Ionic?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ignoring all the views by matching their names, why don't you just use a switch case to match the view names which you have. That way, you don't need to worry about what views are getting used by ionic internally.

Comment: A very nice suggestion!  I could definitely do that, and it would work, but let's say (for the sake of argument and code cleanliness) that I want to only exclude certain views from the logic.  At the moment, this app has about 20 views, and I'd rather avoid having to add a page name to this switch each time I add a new view to my app (or, store them centrally e.g. in an array, as that would consume extra space).

Comment: But as you said, you only want to exclude certain views, so no need to add the new page to existing switch or array. And in case, new page has to be excluded, then it is correct to add it to switch.